# how can i have background shapes with css?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I achieved something like this using a div with the css property of transform: skew();

[image]

however I'd like it to have kind of a curve where the line is going up, so if you could give me a step in the right direction or tell me more about the easiest ways of inserting a responsive svg graphic art to specifically the **background** of the elements or the page itself it'd be much appreciated

EDIT: HERE'S THE CSS USED

```
.skewed-bg{
    background: #830024;
    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -9deg);
    transform: skew(0deg, -9deg);
    margin-top: -200px;
}
.skewed-bg .container{
    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 9deg);
    transform: skew(0deg, 9deg);
    padding-top: 200px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of how this magical shape looks like?

Comment: How about we start with what you have tried, can we see what effort you have made to create this?

Comment: Power Exterminator: the new tv show on Discovery Channel! ;P

Comment: I'm not sure if using skew() is the right approach here...

Comment: i tried with clip-path but it isn't supported in firefox

Comment: @EliecerThoms, the CSS to add an SVG background-image is `background-image: url(path/to/file.svg);` Is there something else you're having trouble with?

Comment: Do you have a link of a site that has this implemented?

Comment: nevermind, this guy here has a tutorial on what I want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2750Vj-hMq8

Comment: thanks for your willingness to help though

Comment: clip-path is supported on Firefox provided you stick to a url

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can also use a `linear-gradient` (again), actually 2 and `background-size`

```css
body {
  width: 80%;/* whatever , can be a fixed width , basicly to show behavior on resize */
  margin: auto;
}
body>div {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, #830024 50%, transparent 50.5%) no-repeat bottom,
    /* bottom part */
    linear-gradient(0deg, #830024, #830024) no-repeat top;
  /* top portion */
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
  background-size: 100% 7em, 100% calc(100% - 7em)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
</div>
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>
```

[codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pyOxyV)

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the skew transform to a pseudo element (like `::after`) without using SVG or affect the main element (also reducing the need for extra HTML element):

```css
header {
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 2em;
}

.skewed-bg {
    background: #830024;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 2em;
    position: relative;
    min-height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.skewed-bg::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -75%; left: 0; right: 0;
  height:100%;
  background:#FFF;
  transform: skew(0deg, -9deg);
}
```

```html
<header>Power</header>
<div class="skewed-bg">
  Quienes Somos.
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6690acn/1/

Comment: looks better, thanks a lot